# Notation for derivative of a 2 argument function w.r.t its second argument

Tags: calculus, notation

For functions of one argument, the "Newton" notation for the derivative of that function is concise and unambiguous.

For example, if I want to express

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x^2 + h) - f(x^2)}{h} = y^2
$$

more succinctly I can write:

$$
f'(x^2) = y
$$

So $'$ is an operator that I can "apply" to any one-argument function.

However, it's not clear to me if there exists a concise way of expressing a multi-argument version. How can I express this:

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x^2, y^2 + h) - f(x^2, y^2)}{h} = y^2
$$

?

i.e. I want to say "the derivative of $f$ with respect to its second argument, when applied to $x^2$ and $y^2$ respectively, is equal to $y^2$.

Using Leibniz notation I can only think of various verbose ways in which I have to "name" each argument of the function before then refering to the derivative w.r.t that "argument". It always seems very verbose and unwieldy.

Is there a standard, concise notation for refering to the derivative of a function w.r.t its nth argument?

Comment: It's not uncommon, particularly in physics, to see the notation $f_{,i}$ which means "$f$ differentiated with respected to its $i$th argument", so e.g. $f_{,1}$ would be $f_x$ and $f_{,2}$ would be $f_y$. Other common notations are $\partial_i f$, which has the advantage that you can refer to the second and third derivatives as e.g. $\partial_i^2f$ or $\partial_i^3f$.

Comment: Thanks Chris - $\partial_i$ looks like exactly what I want.

Comment: @Paul, I'm not certain why you are combining the limit process with the notation for derivatives since they are usually calculated by rules. Also you could use x and y as the subscripts instead of 1 and 2 for clearer notation. In Mathematica they have the longer but clear notation Derivative[1,0][f][x,y] and Derivative[0,1][f][x,y] or higher integers for higher mixed derivatives: Derivative[2,1][f][x,y].

Comment: David I could not think of a clearer way to express what I meant by "the derivative of $f(x^2, y^2)$ with respect to its second argument" than as a limit.

Comment: Actually David I think you may have almost exactly missed my point: Suppose $f(a,b) = ab$ - i.e. f is normal multiplication. Then $(\partial_1 f) (x^2, y^2) = y^2$ whereas $\frac{\partial}{\partial_x} (f(x^2, y^2)) = 2xy^2$. And, to my mind, $(\frac{\partial}{\partial_x} f) (x^2, y^2)$ is just maddeningly ambiguous to my mind. It is exactly this ambiguity/confusion that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Paul, Are you saying that y^2 is the derivative with respect to the second argument of f? Perhaps you are right and I don't understand it, but I don't see how you can evaluate the derivative without knowing what f is.

Comment: I sometimes see $f^{(m,n)}$ written for the $m$th derivative wrt first argument and $n$th derivative wrt to second. This is analogous to how the sequence $f,f',f'',f''',\ldots$ is eventually written as $\ldots,f^{(4)},f^{(5)},\ldots$. Mathematica also uses this notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In differential calculus, you can write $\partial_i f$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f$ for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the ith variable.

In differential geometry, when you want intrinsic expressions, independant of the coordinates, then you can look at the partial derivative of a function with respect to any vector field $X$. This is generally written as $L_X f$ or $X.f$.